# 'For' loop within 'if' (that continues to 'elif') statement

Tags: python, loops

I have a block of if, elif, and else statements. The if statement compares an item within a list then does things with the found item. The elif's and else do not do anything with the list, so I didn't see the point in putting all of it within a for loop.

```
if myText.count(myItem for myItem in myList):
    doSomething using myText and myItem
elif otherThing1:
    doStuff
elif otherThing2:
    doOther stuff
else:
    forget this, go have a drink
```

I get an error in the first line of course, but is there a Pythonic way to get what I'm looking for without having to restructure my entire code?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with `myItem` inside the indented block. In your above example, `myItem` is part of a generator expression, and doesn't have any meaning (or value) outside that expression.

Comment: If `myText` is of type `str`, then `myItem for myItem in myList` had better return a string... which it doesn't, because it returns a generator. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Can you describe what you actually want to do instead of trying to [troubleshoot the alleged solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, myItem is type str.

I am trying to see if a str inside of a list of strs is inside of a bigger str (myText), and then do things with both myItem and myText.

Comment: That does not describe what you're trying to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a str (myText).
I have a list of str (myList).
if myText contains one of the strs in myList, i want to replace that part of myText with something else 
if the none of the strs in myList are in myText, I want to edit myText in one of a few other ways.

Comment: You're trying to find a substring in each string from a list of strings??? You're explanation is a little confusing and your sudo code isn't helping it. What are you trying to do with / why do you need all of those elif statements?

Comment: sorry, I was using pseudo code so it wouldn't be like asking people here to write my code for me. is there a way I can edit the original question or do I have to delete it and ask a different one?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm learning about generators right now and that was the first thing I saw when I saw that "If" statement. Question: is it even possible to do something like that. Wouldn't you need to create a generator with a yield in it and feed the next to the "If" in the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to test whether or not an item is in a list, an easy way to do that is:

```
if item in list:
    do something
```

Comment: I already know the items within a list are going to be type str, I need to do something with the item only if that item is found in a bigger str

Answer (score 1):

```
for myItem in myList :
    if myItem in myText :
        doSomething using myText and myItem
    elif otherThing1:
        doStuff
    elif otherThing2:
        doOther stuff
    else:
        forget this, go have a drink
```

Comment: I had that at first, the problem was the elifs and else would execute multiple times while they were looping through the list, and I only want them to execute once after the whole list was looped through and nothing done.

Answer (score 0):

Your words:
"I am trying to see if a str inside of a list of strs is inside of a bigger str (myText), and then do things with both myItem and myText. I only want the "else" bit to execute after the if statement iterated through all items of myList and didn't find anything."

```
count = 0
for myItem in mylist:
    if myItem in myText:
        count += 1
        do something with myItem and myText
if count == 0:
    do what you want to do when if finds nothing
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do the the elifs? You are looking for a substring in a larger string. It's going to evaluate to true or false. Why do you need 4 logical statements?

You have to realize that if you put your if/else statement inside of a loop, that every time the loop runs, it's going to either do what evaluates to True or False

Comment: I only want the "else" bit to execute after the if statement iterated through all items of myList and didn't find anything.

Comment: yes it did, but I ended up using a for..else method instead.

Comment: @rasonage Nice move! I totally forgot about putting else after a for loop in python. :) This is exactaly when you would want to use it.